# Strange bugs while rendering with OpenGL under Qml Scene

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, qml

As a hobby, I am experimenting with OpenGL and write my own silly engine with Qt+OpenGL. Last success was building Entity System Framework which could render scene with shadows (by render-to-texture to RenderBuffer) with attached physics engine (BulletPhysics).

After that I updated to Qt 5.2 and was totally expressed by Qml (not trying to use it before). I'm experimented about 2d qml graphics a bit, and decide to use qml for user interface, but reject 2d project and return to 3d. I created new qml project, try to render some stuff under qml as in [Scene Graph - OpenGL Under QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/scenegraph-openglunderqml.html) example. After that I moved my old code from 3d project to new project, with some small refactoring (which should not affect anything).

In this moment I get tired with some strange bug. It seems like first frame is rendered as needed, but after that something goes wrong.

[image: Scene view]
*This is a some less or more normally frame (before any moving)*

In the left top corner I am output depth buffer (shadow map). In the right top corner I make some custom scrollers with qml. I am using this scrollers for changing shadow map rotating and moving camera. When scrollers are centered, nothing moves. When I change something, scene became ugly and I can't wonder why.

[image: Scene view after some shadow map rotate]
*This is the frame after some shadow map rotating*

I see that shadow map depth buffer not changed (why? o_0) and shadow in scene goes wrong. But not only shadow is failed after refactoring my old code to qml project. When I move camera, bugs became more strange.

[image: Scene after moving camera down (-Z)]
*This is the frame after moving camera down (-Z)*

Scene is rendered under qml by using:

```
connect(window, &QQuickWindow::beforeRendering, this, &MyApp::renderScene, Qt::DirectConnection);
```

In renderScene I:

- Do some OpenGL conveyor setup (to prevent changes by Qml Scene Graph, may be excess);

  ```
  glViewport(0, 0, window->width(), window->height());

  glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
  glClearDepth(1);
  glDepthRange(0,1);
  glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
  ```
- Call BulletPhysics to calculate physics (in test scene - two falling cubes)
- Render shadow map (depth-only) to RenderBuffer (2048x2048 texture, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24)
- Render scene to RenderBuffer (two GL_RGBA8 textures for color and normals and one GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24 for depth)
- Render two 2d quads - fullscreen (scene render with all textures from renderbuffer to render with shadows) and side screen (top left corner's texture from depthbuffer)

I am tired to hunt what is going on. glGetError shows nothing.

[image: Scene with camera moved]
*Moved camera one more time by XY-axes. Man's horn silhouette is still visible and make strange effect*

Some more screenshots:

[image: Old project]
*Old project (without qml)*

[image: Old project - big screenshot]
*Old project (big screenshot)*

[image: Broken resize]
*On new project, window resizing is broken too*

What can it be?

Environment: Qt Creator 3.0.0, Qt 5.2.0, Linux (Kubuntu 13.10) 64-bit, HD 7750

OpenGL: in old project I set up 3.3, new project use 4.3 (as far as I remember)

P.S. Depth map is distorted because I use some additional distortion in shaders to improve shadows in scene center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An inspiration came upon me after a day without an answer and many previous days!

I have suspected that something was wrong with the depth buffer and tried to output to debug texture ids that used to render to and used to render to fullscreen quad. I tried switch off render-to-texture buffer swapping and much more. But I can't even think that real problem is at Qml's side.

glDepthMask(GL_TRUE); // 42!

One this line is like `42` - answer to all questions. It's seems that Qml is calling `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);` before first render frame (but after emit `&QQuickWindow::beforeRendering` signal). Result of this call was that only first my frame really rendered with writing to depth buffer. Why I think that `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);` is called only once? Because FPS is noticeably decreased after I inserted my "42", and increased after I inserted `glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);` in the end of slot that used to render my scene.

Now I can freely rotate "Sun" (shadow) and move camera without any visual bugs.

Yippee!

[image: Result in new project]

Comment: this was the answer for me :D i use glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) with no results but using glDepthMask(GL_TRUE) does the trick in QML.

Comment: when i was fight with that bug, i tried glEnable and glDisable with all states that I use - depth test, blend, cull face... but without any real results. glDepthMask is too much unobvious to be remembered and suspected...

Comment: Excellent answer - although sadly I don't know why its the case (which fills me with some dread for the future) I've spent ages trying to get OpenGL to work under QML following Sean Harmer's blog - while it wasn't looking right and thought it was probably something to do with the depth buffer, I just wouldn't have found this without your help.Txs.

Comment: StuReeks, I render my scene under (before) QML Layer. When QML renders first, it switch off depth buffer changing. Shadow buffer from Sun's position stops refreshing after first frame and this is frozing shadows. Also when moving camera or resizing window - depth buffer wasn't reset. And shadow glitches. And sometimes some objects or parts doesn't renders because depth buffer prevent them doing this.